# Official stance on jailbroken ipod/iphone support?

Tags: support, scope, superuser

https://superuser.com/questions/33893/ipod-touch-2g-3-0-jailbreak-broke-springboard-can-i-fix-it-without-reinstalling

I am not disagreeing with Diago's call on this question. What is our official stance on question concerning jailbroken software on ipod/iphone?  I am not saying this is illegal, wrong, or anything like that. Just curious is all because of some debate on phones/music players.

We have had people ask How to jailbreak and where to find resources on them. I think those questions are fine and people have answered with great resources for them to use.  This deals with questions beyond jailbreaking the device itself.

I always show people this forum for support for things like that because there is so many knowledgable people there: http://forums.macrumors.com/forumdisplay.php?f=105

Also for reference a previous discussion on iphone/ipod support: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/are-iphone-ipod-ipod-touch-questions-computer-related-superuser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was probably the first who started allowing jailbreaking questions. I think it is now standard operating procedure to allow jailbreaking questions or questions about jailbroken devices. If necessary, the mods will put a note on the question or in the comments basically saying that SuperUser does not advocate any behavior that may potentially brick your device.

Comment: It was you. You son of a... haha. That is just fine with me, I just want to make sure everyone is on the same page and saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope that I was not offensive in any way in my reaction to the comments on whether to support or not to support jailbreaking questions.

I don't think directing people to another support site is good for any community's development. Doing so might lead to an understanding that certain type of questions are not appreciated.

People should feel confident that they can at least get some answers at one site, without being redirected to x-number of a external support sites right from the beginning. The reason is obvious, they can search for tags at the same very site, read related questions thanks to the "Related questions" links, and so on. The whole community benefits from that, as the problem solving skills of the members gets better in time.

Comment: Nope, you were not offensive at all. You brought up a legitimate concern. That is why I brought discussion/question to meta.  Links can be good additions to answers most of the time.  In that case, that forum was specific to that topic, so it could help greatly, especialy if the question recieved very little feedback. Links only can be bad as you have stated though.